# Ошибка индекса c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
t2.Tick += (o, v) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 397) continue;// для проверки
        new Thread(() => { list[i].ping(t2.Interval); }).Start();
        dvg[4, list[i].numPrint].Value = list[i].ipStatus;
    }
};
```

list.Count = 397. Когда i = 397, то заходит в цикл, создает поток. Почему игнорируется условие? подскажите знающие. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Замыкания захватывают переменные, а не их значения.

Comment: т е i=397 при создании потока потому что в момент времени, когда поток создается, она уже была увеличена? я верно понял?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все верно. В вашем коде

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (i >= 397) continue;// для проверки
    new Thread(() => { list[i].ping(t2.Interval); }).Start();
    dvg[4, list[i].numPrint].Value = list[i].ipStatus;
}
```

Поток стартует не мгновенно, поэтому к моменту старта потока переменная `i` уже была увеличена. Если вам надо захватывать значение переменной `i`, то вы можете сначала скопировать его в другую локальную переменную, например

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (i >= 397) continue;// для проверки
    var j=i; // копия
    new Thread(() => { list[j].ping(t2.Interval); }).Start(); // захват копии переменной
    dvg[4, list[i].numPrint].Value = list[i].ipStatus;
}
```

Comment: думаю копия это глупо, легче оперировать переменной только с одного потока, и тогда она не привысит своего значения. Во всяком случае спасибо .

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я ничего не понял

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц кроме "спасибо"