# Как лямбда функции преобразуются в ParameterizedThreadStart и ThreadStart

Tags: c#, многопоточность, lambda

Разбирался с потоками и столкнулся со следующим.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
            threads[i] = new Thread(x=>Func(i));
            Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            threads[i].Start();
        
        void Func(int numThread)=>Console.WriteLine(numThread);
```

Вывод:

```
3
3
3
```

Думал из-за цикла `i` быстро становится `3` и все потоки создаются с `Func(3)`, добавил критические секции, предполагая, что это изменит ситуацию, но увы.
Нашел способ конкретно инициализировать другую переменную и закинуть в неё `i`:

```
int j = i;
threads[i] = new Thread(x=>Func(j));
```

Тогда вывод становится ожидаемым `012`.
Но ситуацию с непониманием как конкретно тред преобразует лямбду к нужным делегатам непонятно. А так же почему все они запускаются с тройкой `Func(3)`, здесь что-то типо замыкания?

Comment: Здесь не типа, а именно замыкания и происходят.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851360/179763, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011408/179763, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009090/179763, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884117/179763

Comment: @tym32167 такие вопросы можно сразу дубликатить